# Sudden change in profile page across Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, design, profile-page

I noticed that at some point today the UI for the activity pages on people's profile pages has changed for example:

[image: screen shot of user activity page on Raspberry PI]

The colors on the privilege and badge progress bars have changed as well as the location of the settings buttons for those progress bars.

Is there any reason for this UI change or is it some kind of bug?

Comment: Hope not a bug, may be their fix for this [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350905/2451726) and some other design issues.

Comment: I don't mind the repositioning of the control, but those muted badge colors are much harder to see.  What was wrong with brightly and loudly proclaiming your next target?  Also, they fixed one alignment problem by creating another -- look at how your next badge in the center section is awkwardly misaligned with your next tag badge in the left section -- not far enough to be clearly "not intended to align", but not aligned either.  Can't unsee!

Comment: @MonicaCellio I understand what you're saying about the bottom row alignment in the badges box. I'll explore trying to align them better.

Comment: @Hynes Note that for moderators there is now a line break in the "helpful flags" line for users with >1000 flags, due to the number of declined flags appearing afterwards in parentheses.  If this is worth posting as a separate question I'll be happy to do so.

Comment: @Hynes I offered a suggestion in another answer here.

Comment: I don't have a problem seeing anything. Perhaps it is the difference in your displays and mine (HP L1906 on a desktop)?

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any reason for this UI change or is it some kind of bug?

[The reasons for these updates can be found within this Meta.SO post.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351378/2640230)

> the colors on the privilege and badge progress bars have changed…

These were lightened so that the copy could be more easily read.

> …as well as the location of the settings buttons for those progress bars.

Yes these were moved out of the padding areas of the boxes, placed next to the labels of the item you could change.

Answer (score 6):

I appreciate the [effort to improve this part of the display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297766/162102).  To improve readability (good!) we got faded colors, which are a lot harder for me to see.  Look at the gold progress indicator:

[image: MSO example]

Also notice (and this was true before too) that we have two progress indicators side by side, one for tag badges and one for other badges, and their representations are completely different!  One shows the badge name *on* a color-coded progress bar; the other shows the badge as a badge and separately shows a progress bar.  We could bring these closer together:

[image: design proposal: show next badge as a badge and show a tag-badge-style progress bar below it]

This is a rough sketch and should be refined.  The idea is to align the latest and next badges horizontally, put a progress bar below the latter with the numeric part above it like in tag badges, and try to line up the tag and other badge sections better.  Not shown: it might then make more sense to put the gear over on the right, where the circled numbers are.

This eliminates the contrast problem entirely -- no more text over progress.  All badges look like badges, including their brighter colors.  All progress bars seen within a few hundred pixels of each other look the same.

Finally, I know this was done to align the containers.  The badges section just doesn't have as much stuff to show as the rep/tag-badges section.  That extra white space is going to have to go somewhere, or you're going to need to find something else small to add to the badge section.  You've got extra white space now, too, at the bottom.  My proposal moves the white space and maybe consumes a bit more of it, but you've still got a white-space problem.

Comment: Appreciate the post. I have some pending commits which address the alignment issues within the badges box. The idea of removing the badge / privilege progress bars altogether in favor the smaller progress bar is good one as well.